# Hibernate Envers: Audit @CollectionTable field

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I try to audit `Order` class which has `List<OrderItem>` field.
The `Order` class looks like this:

```
class Order {
    @Audited
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "order_order_item", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"))
    List<OrderItem> items;
}
```

And for `OrderItem` class looks like this:

```
class OrderItem {
    private Integer quantity;
    private Long itemId;
}
```

Each order must contains unique OrderItem (distinguish by itemId).

The problem is that I try to create `Order` which has multiple `OrderItem`s, each item is unique, but hibernate throw exception said:

```
A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [order_order_item_AUD#{SETORDINAL=1, REV=DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 16, revisionDate = Oct 9, 2016 1:38:12 PM), Order_id=57, REVTYPE=ADD}]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [order_order_item_AUD#{SETORDINAL=1, REV=DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 16, revisionDate = Oct 9, 2016 1:38:12 PM), Order_id=57, REVTYPE=ADD}]
```

I think that problem probably be that envers use same identifier for different `OrderItem` because envers only see `order_id` from `@JoinColumn` and treat it as identifier.

I don't known how to tell envers to use both `itemId` and `order_id` as identifier of revision or maybe I misunderstand the problem.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: so the primary key in your case it composite of itemId and order_id?

Comment: From class definitions that I gave, it is not explicitly set primary key to be composite of itemId and order_id because I don't have order_id inside `OrderItem` definition but I may create unique constraint in RDBMS to make sure about that.

Comment: From my understanding, I think that `@ElementCollection` also doesn't care about primary key, it just fetch/join items from `@CollectionTable` using `@JoinColumn` as a join point.

Comment: "tell hibernate to use both itemId and order_id as identifier"  what are you trying to identify , why you even using collection table here? from what i understand you need a jointable not a collection table

Comment: @AmerQarabsa Thanks, I'm trying your suggestion. I'll update about it.

Comment: If that ends up not working, please post the code which causes the exception, and the code where you're creating the `Order`

Answer (score 2):

Instead you may want to consider mapping this as follows:

```
@Embeddable
public class OrderItemId implements Serializable {
  private Long orderId;

  private Long itemId;
}

@Entity
public class OrderItem {
  @EmbeddedId
  private OrderItemId id;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("orderId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
  private Order order;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("itemId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
  private Item item;
}
```

If you want to keep the `@ElementCollection` mapping, you may need to include an `@OrderColumn` annotation and make sure you implement proper hashCode/equals methods that use the item_id and order_id values only.